# How to group items in laravel and echo the value if group count is larger than a certain number

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

```php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(date) AS numberofreservations, date FROM reservations GROUP BY date HAVING numberofreservations >= $max";//#per day
```

I just switched to laravel and I'm trying to get a variable based on this sql, $max would be in controller from another database which i already got but how doI group them like this?

Comment: Something like this may work: `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(date) AS numberofreservations, date FROM reservations GROUP BY date HAVING COUNT(date) >= $max"`   Also I'd look into using placeholders to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent :

```
$max = 1; // example
$sql = Reservation::selectRaw('count(date) as numberofreservations, date')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->havingRaw('numberofreservations >= ' . $max)
    ->get();
```

Or Query Builder :

```
$max = 1; // example
$sql = DB::table('reservations')
    ->selectRaw('count(date) as numberofreservations, date')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->havingRaw('numberofreservations >= ' . $max)
    ->get();
```

##### Debug :

```
$sql = DB::table('reservations')
    ->selectRaw('count(date) as numberofreservations, date')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->havingRaw('numberofreservations >= ' . $max)
    ->dd();
```

```
"select count(date) as numberofreservations, date from `reservations` group by `date` having numberofreservations >= 1"
[]
```